# How can I stop my iPhone tagging a particular face?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

With the new update to iOS 10, the Photos app searches for faces in your pictures and groups them into albums.

One of my friends has an Android phone that superimposes a facebook chat bubble in the top right of her screen at all times showing her boyfriend's profile picture.  The Photos app has recognised his face within the bubble in all the screenshots she has sent me and these now appear as an album in faces.

How can I tell the app that I don't want this face to be tagged as a face?  Selecting them and pressing delete offers to delete the photos entirely, similarly I don't want to press hide as this removes photos from the library.  I have also tried "not this face", however this doesn't solve my problem either.

Comment: Right now, I don't think it's possible to say 'not this face'.